# Can't refer to the element

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I am working on a automation application with python and selenium.But ı got stucked clicking on the "I don't have a phone number seciton.
[To understand my problem better please look at the image that i have uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk75l.png)

I have tried the following codes (One for class name and one for Xpath)but nothing worked properly:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*["I don't have mobile phone"]''').click()


driver.find_element_by_class_name('toggle-link link_has-no-phone').click()
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps :

1. wait for the element to load and become visible
2. make sure the xpath is correct or right-click on the element in inspect mode and click on copy as Xpath

   3 - make sure there's only one element with that path and it's
   clickable